# Network Printing

Tags: printing

In our office we all use Windows operating system. We have a network printer (Canon LBP 3300) connected with a windows pc. If I use Ubuntu alone, how to give print with the network printer?

Comment: For my brother printer, I think it would work like this: Install the driver, select it's connected to the network, then add //pcname/sharename as location... give it a try, as I cannot write a step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu system, point your browser at `http://localhost:631/admin`, click on `Find New Printer`, or `Add Printer`. Your printer is probably `ipp://IPAddress`